# How to add quantity based product prices in Prestashop with addon price?

Tags: prestashop

How do we enter prices for below

1 Banner  = Base price $20 + Artwork $5 = $25
  2 Banners = Base price $20 x 2 ($40) + Artwork $5 = $45
  3 Banners = Base price $20 x 3 ($60) + Artwork $5 = $65

Currently Prestashop does not allow to have a fixed addon price for artwork variable. 
  It should not get multiplied when the quantity increases. (Artwork is a fixed cost)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should do creating specifics prices for each quantity. In specific price only modify the quantity value. Also, a list with prices and saves will appear in product page.